# React jsx style tag not applied to tags returned by functions

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to apply styling to tags that are generated from a for loop inside a function. The problem is that styling within a  tag doesn't apply to these generated tags. Possibly because they're generated after the styling is applied? I'm not sure. Here's an example:

```
generateTags = (size) => {
    let tags = []
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tags.push(<img className="image-tag" src={this.state.imagePath} alt="image" key={Math.random() * Math.floor(100000)}/>)
    }
    return tags
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <div className="left-container">
                {this.generateTags(10)}
            </div>
        <style jsx> {`
            .main { <-- This is properly applied
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .image-tag { <-- This doesn't work
                position: absolute;
                width: 50px;
            }
        `} </style>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The width: 50px is not applied to the image, and nothing I place makes any difference. But when I add styling within the tag like this:

```
<img className="image-tag" style={{width: "50px"}} src={this.state.imagePath} alt="image" key={Math.random() * Math.floor(100000)}/>
```

Then the style is applied correctly. Does this mean I can't have css within the style tag if the elements are return from a function?

Comment: can you verify that the style tag and its contents is indeed rendered correcrly on the output page?

Comment: why dont you give the styles inline to the main div and the img tags

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I find it much more readable to have the styles in their usual format nicely nested at the end of the file. Also the style tag ensures that the styles won't be applied to the same classNames present in other components.

Comment: @NikosM. The style is applied only when it's inline within the tag itself. I notice a chance instantly. When the style is within the jsx style tag, it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using [Styled JSX](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx). One of the principles of Styled JSX is that the CSS is component specific. Since your `<img>` tags are being created outside of the `render()` function where your styles are defined, they are not being applied.

In this instance, I would recommend to instead have a `GenerateTags` React component, instead of a function. That way, you can generate your tags as needed, as well as apply component specific styling, like so:

```
GenerateTags = (props) => {
    const {size} = props

    let tags = []

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tags.push(i)
    }

    return(
        <>
            {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                <img className="image-tag" src={this.state.imagePath} alt="image" key={Math.random() * Math.floor(100000)}/>
            ))}

            <style jsx>{`
                // This will now work as it is in the same scope as the component
                .image-tag {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 50px;
                }
            `}</style>
        </>
    )

    return tags
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <div className="left-container">
                <GenerateTags size={10} />
            </div>
        <style jsx> {`
            .main { <-- This is properly applied
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        `} </style>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Otherwise, if you wanted these styles to be applied outside of the scope of the component, you could use the `global` option:

```
<style jsx global>
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: I had forgotten about global styles. Looks like that's the best fix for what I'm trying to do and it works great. Thanks!